# The For each loop in the end won't produce any output | Powershell

Tags: powershell

This Script won't work and i simply can't wrap my head around how to properly append the array of objects, maybe i've made an error with crating the array or the object i'm fairly new to powershell and this is a bit to much if one could refactor this code it would be an amazing help.

If one even could sort the array afterwards descendent with the Hash that would be crazy.

Thanks a lot.

```
[Array]$FileListOriginal = @()
[Array]$FileListDestination = @()
$Source1 = 'C:\'
$Temp1 = 'H:\'

Class File {
    [string]$hash
    [string]$fullName;
    }

Function Get-FileList ($Path,$Destination) {

    [Array]$FileListOriginalTemp = @()
    [Array]$FileListDestinationTemp = @()

    Foreach($file in (gci -Recurse -File -Path $Path)){
        
        $hash = Get-FileHash $file.fullName
        
        
        $FileListOriginalTemp += [File]@{hash = $hash.Hash; fullName = $Hash.Path}
    }
    Foreach($file in (gci -Recurse -File -Path $Destination)){
        
        $hash = Get-FileHash $file.fullName

        $FileListDestinationTemp += [File]@{hash = $hash.Hash; fullName = $Hash.Path}  
    }
    $FileListOriginal = $FileListOriginalTemp
    $FileListDestination = $FileListDestinationTemp
}

Get-FileList -Path $Source1 -Destination $Temp1

foreach ($object in $FileListOriginal){
    write $object.hash
    write $object.fullName}
```

Comment: Variables in PowerShell are _scoped_ - `$FileListOriginal` is created inside the scope of the `Get-FileList` function, so it stops existing once that function returns :)

Comment: No thats not correct its created outside the Function and since i couldn't append the Array from outside i tried to make FileListOriginal = FileListOriginalTemp :)

Comment: The `$FileListOriginal` created outside the function _is not the same_ `$FileListOriginal` as inside the function :) You should `return` (or otherwise output) the lists from the function

Comment: I see i see so how come that in other functions i can access vaiables from the outside of the Function but with this array i cannot? This is quite confusing. i have other scripts where it works just fine and i can use Variables over diffrent Functions. (i declare them and don't manipulate them tho)

Comment: You can _read from_ variables declared outside the local scope, but as soon as you start _writing_ to them (eg. `$FileListOriginal = ...`), PowerShell will create a new local variable and hide the external.

Comment: Alright, thats quite dumb imo but whatever. Why would anyone want that thats ugh one to much for today, gladly imma go home now.

Comment: It's quite useful actually - it avoids situations where you import someone else's module/function and they accidentally overwrite variables in the calling scope. I've provided an answer as to how you should re-design your function instead.

Comment: Well i see i guess thats where scripting differs from coding it feels a bit weird ngl :D (one file a class and here i'm like everything on one paper is just ugh)

Answer (score 0):

By default, writing to a variable declared in a parent scope will cause PowerShell to hide it behind a local variable.

Since writing to variables outside the local scope is a bit of an anti-pattern, you should output the lists from the function instead:

```
[Array]$FileListOriginal = @()
[Array]$FileListDestination = @()
$Source1 = 'C:\'
$Temp1 = 'H:\'

Class File {
    [string]$hash
    [string]$fullName
}

Function Get-FileList ($Path,$Destination) {

    [Array]$FileListOriginalTemp = @()
    [Array]$FileListDestinationTemp = @()

    Foreach($file in (gci -Recurse -File -Path $Path)){
        $hash = Get-FileHash $file.fullName
        
        $FileListOriginalTemp += [File]@{hash = $hash.Hash; fullName = $Hash.Path}
    }

    Foreach($file in (gci -Recurse -File -Path $Destination)){
        
        $hash = Get-FileHash $file.fullName

        $FileListDestinationTemp += [File]@{hash = $hash.Hash; fullName = $Hash.Path}  
    }

    # return from function and output the two lists
    return $FileListOriginalTemp,$FileListDestinationTemp
}

$FileListOriginal,$FileListDestination = Get-FileList -Path $Source1 -Destination $Temp1

foreach ($object in $FileListOriginal){
    write $object.hash
    write $object.fullName
}
```

Comment: Well thanks now i just ned to sort the array and i can implement this in the script tommorrow and my weekend may be saved. I mean thanks for adding the Return Statement but as much i could've done aswell i simply did not consider such a option (imo quite absurd). If anyone is willing to explain to me why it would be usefull to not beeing able to change the Variable outside of the scope without a return statement please enlighten me.

Comment: @Syzard sorting/re-ordering a collection is fairly straightforward in PowerShell: `$FileListOriginal = $FileListOriginal |Sort-Object FullName`

Comment: Thank you very much :P

Comment: @Syzard actually you can change an array outside the scope by specifying the scope of the variable in the function:  $Script:FileListOriginal = .... However, that said, it breaks the black-box functionality of a Function and thereby limiting its reusability.

Comment: Well thats good to know, thanks.